# Function in the DocuSign API to download CSV Form Data

Tags: rest, csv, docusignapi

I've been writing some DocuSign API functionality.  I noticed that through the actual user interface you can download CSV form data for completed envelopes.

Is there a way to call this function through the API?  So far, I am getting the reponse per receipient and saving that myself into a txt file.  But as it seems the functionality to download to CSV is in the UI, I am hoping there's a way to do this through the API as well?

Cheers,

J

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the online API documentation for REST/SOAP, it does not appear as an option.  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation